# Deserialization JSON with embeded types

Tags: .net, vb.net, json.net

I have the following JSON:

```
{
    "type": "champion",
    "version": "6.24.1",
    "data": {
        "Jax": {
            "id": 24,
            "key": "Jax",
            "name": "Jax",
            "title": "Grandmaster at Arms",
            "image": {
                "full": "Jax.png",
                "sprite": "champion1.png",
                "group": "champion",
                "x": 48,
                "y": 48,
                "w": 48,
                "h": 48
            }
        },
        "Sona": {
            "id": 37,
            "key": "Sona",
            "name": "Sona",
            "title": "Maven of the Strings",
            "image": {
                "full": "Sona.png",
                "sprite": "champion3.png",
                "group": "champion",
                "x": 288,
                "y": 0,
                "w": 48,
                "h": 48
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The RiotRequestManager gathers the string. I want to be able to access the image strings for "full" and "sprite" from the class LeagueObjectManager. I get a list of names and provided the method, I wanted to be able to pull the image using a name from LeagueObject. I am clicking on their name on a list and trying to return the image full string. Everything I try provides a null response.

I have the following classes:

```
Imports Newtonsoft.Json
Public Class LeagueObjectManager
    Private rrm As New RiotRequestManager
    Private lc As LeagueObjectContainer
    Private count As Integer

    Public Sub New(ByVal strRegion As String, ByVal strMode As String)
        lc = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of LeagueObjectContainer)(rrm.returnLeagueItems(strRegion, strMode))
        count = lc.data.Count()
    End Sub

    Public Function returnNames() As String()
        Dim strReturn(count - 1) As String
        Dim errorCount As Integer = 0
        Dim counter As Integer = 0
        For i = 0 To count - 1
            If Not (lc.data.ElementAt(i).Value.name = "error") Then
                strReturn(counter) = lc.data.ElementAt(i).Value.name
                counter += 1
            Else
                errorCount += 1
                ReDim Preserve strReturn(count - 1 - errorCount)
            End If
        Next
        Return strReturn
    End Function
End Class

Public Class LeagueObjectContainer
    Public Property type As String
    Public Property version As String
    Public Property data As SortedDictionary(Of String, LeagueObject)
End Class

Public Class LeagueObject
    Public Property id As Integer
    Public Property key As String
    Public Property name As String = "error"
    Public Property title As String
    Public Property image As SortedDictionary(Of String, LeagueImage)
    Public Property group As String
    Public Property tags As String()
    Public Property enemytips As String
    Public Property allytips As String
End Class

Public Class LeagueImage
    Public Property full As String
    Public Property sprite As String
End Class
```

Comment: I cant see where/how you are trying to access the Image info.  Can you show that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several efficiencies you can apply to what you have.  Mainly, you do not need another class to act as the manager: any methods or additional properties you want to add can be added to the existing class.  Using slightly more idiomatic names:

```
Public Class DataItem
    Public Property id As Integer
    Public Property key As String
    Public Property name As String = ""
    Public Property title As String
    Public Property image As ImageInfo

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return name
    End Function
End Class

Public Class ImageInfo
    Public Property full As String
    Public Property sprite As String
    Public Property group As String
    Public Property x As Integer
    Public Property y As Integer
    Public Property w As Integer
    Public Property h As Integer
End Class
```

I left all the Image properties there, even if you are not interested in them. Then the container class can be an amalgam of the container and manager classes:

```
Public Class LeagueManager
    Public Property type As String
    Public Property version As String
    Public Property data As Dictionary(Of String, DataItem)

    Public Sub New()

    End Sub

    ' could/should be As IEnumerable(Of String)
    Public Function GetPlayerNames() As String()

        ' enumerate Values collection of dictionary,
        '  filter out those with no name 
        '  select/pick/use the DataItem.name 
        '  put them in alpha order
        '  convert from IEnumerable to an array
        Dim names = data.Values.AsEnumerable().
                        Where(Function(j) String.IsNullOrEmpty(j.name) = False).
                        Select(Function(q) q.name).
                        OrderBy(Function(k) k).
                        ToArray()
        Return names
    End Function

    Public Function GetPlayer(name As String) As DataItem
        ' first first DataItem where the names match
        Return data.Values.
            FirstOrDefault(Function(q) String.Compare(name, q.name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) = 0)
    End Function

    Public Function GetPlayers() As DataItem()
        Return data.Values.AsEnumerable().Cast(Of DataItem).ToArray()
    End Function
End Class
```

1. You dont have to combine them: its an option.  The more complicated the json related classes are, the less likely I would be to do it.
2. The code to get the player names was streamlined
3. There are several methods to access the data items
4. I have no idea where some props come from like `allytips`.  I guess you are trying to use 1 class for more than one json?  If so, I might not combine the manager and container.
5. A plain `Dictionary` is used rather than a `SortedDictionary`.  It is easy enough to get whatever you want from the `Dictionary` in whatever form or order you want.
6. The `ToString()` override on `DataItem` should be useful in debugging.

If you combine the manager and the container, do not deserialize from the constructor, I think you'll get into an endless loop when JSON.NET creates another one for deserializing.  An explicit Load method would allow you to (re)load data for other parameters/regions etc.

The `GetPlayer(string)` methods returns a single `DataItem` where the *name* matches (case insensitive).  This does not rely on the `Dictionary` keys, but the actual names from the `DataItems` which hides the implememtation, but  `Nothing` can be returned if items can be removed/deleted:

```
Dim JaxData = myData.GetPlayer("jax")
If JaxData IsNot Nothing Then
    ...
End If
```

This would provide another way to iterate the collection using the names returned from `GetPlayerNames()`.  You could add `Count`, `HasPlayer` and whatever other properties and methods you need.  As for the image, it is just another property on DataItem:

```
Dim jstr = ...

Dim leagueData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of LeagueManager)(jstr)

' get array of names
Dim names = leagueData.GetPlayerNames()

Dim di As DataItem
For Each s As String In names
    ' get DataItem object for player named in 's'
    di = leagueData.GetPlayer(s)
    If di IsNot Nothing Then
        Console.WriteLine("{0} aka '{1}' uses image: '{2}'", di.name,
                          di.title, di.image.sprite)
    Else
        ' very unlikely:
        Console.WriteLine("Cannot find {0}", s)
    End If

Next
```

Results:

> Jax
>   Sona
>   Jax aka 'Grandmaster at Arms' uses image: 'champion1.png'
>   Sona aka 'Maven of the Strings' uses image: 'champion3.png'

Comment: Nevermind, I got it. Thank you so much, again. I apparently am missing a while level of programming knowledge.

Comment: Looks like there was a previous comment that was retracted?  In case you are referring to the linq extensions for `GetPlayerNames()` , I added some comments to explain.  They are a great way to avoid tedious loops around  multiple `If/ElseIf` conditions. It also avoids that awful `ReDim Preserve` (the 90s called and wanted it back).  Please upvote the answer if it helped.

Comment: Something wasn't working, but it was my fault and I figured it out. Yea, I the linq commands seem very useful. It's making my current project a lot easier and better. Thank you :)

Comment: Good to hear.  Not for nothing, but you can/should upvote any Q or A you stumble upon which informs or teaches you anything.  Upvotes help others find good answers and is a way of saying 'thanks'.

Answer (score 3):

Two problems:

1. Your JSON syntax is invalid. You're missing the final closing bracket.
2. Your class hierarchy doesn't match the JSON structure.

If your JSON structure is fixed and can't be changed, you can get the associated class hierarchy by choosing `Edit/Paste Special/Paste JSON as Classes` in Visual Studio.

Comment: Thank you, I fixed the Json string. I pulled it from a much larger string and thought I had all the brackets. I'll try to do this first thing tomorrow. Thank you for your answers. I was letting leagueobject pull double duty and combine but allytips is something with the champion still. The api call can add more information depending on the request. So, Plutonix mentioned null values as a problem but I'm bound to have null variables a lot but the form calls are pretty specific.

Comment: @RalphMaurmeier: You're welcome. FYI here's a good JSON parser - https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com.